# Информация о качестве принимаемого сигнала соседних базовых станций LTE

Tags: android

Не могу получить информацию о соседних базовых станций в сети LTE. Для сети GSM все находит нормально с помощью класса NeighboringCellInfo, для LTE выводит NULL. Собственно как достать информацию о соседних сотах в сети LTE?

Comment: а в чём, собственно, вопрос? переформулируйте, пожалуйста, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по комментарию `TODO - handle LTE and eHRPD (or find they can't be supported)` в исходном коде NeighboringCellInfo, получить из него эту информацию не получится. Возможно, вам поможет [CellSignalStrengthLte](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellSignalStrengthLte.html).